# Why do I get the wrong result when evaluating an expression?

Tags: c#

```
int[] a = {5, 6, 10}
int n = a.Max() + a.Sum() % 10;
Console.Write(n);
```

The code prints out 11, but I would expect 1 because 31 % 10 = 1. Can anybody explain why the code above gives a different answer?

Comment: So do you do better maths then the computer ? :-)

Comment: Sure he does! A computer rounds too much.

Comment: Your question doesn't show research efforts. Please have a look at how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please look here for tips on writing a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @mmushtaq Don't just post the link to every question you see. The OP followed all of those tips, so your comment is quite unwarranted.

Comment: @StasIvanov What would that research entail? Please don't get caught up in this hostile culture where every simple question is automatically considered bad. This is not a bad question, and if you don't understand operator precedence, there's nothing you can search for to find the right answer. "Doesn't show research effort" isn't the same thing as "Didn't read an introduction to programming in C#".

Comment: @Luaan I could not agree more. This is a perfectly good question. Yet downvoted twice, and comments are either mocking in nature, or mcve hammers.

Comment: @Luaan research means at least googling C# expression evaluation rules. Second (but not least), the initial header of the question was misleading (now it's better). Third, the question required efforts from the reader in order to be understood. Actually, initial research before asking on SO answers such questions.

Comment: @StasIvanov How do you know to search for "C# expression evaluation rules", when you don't know what an expression or evaluation is? What title would you use?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Comment: @Luaan surely you did more than I for the community, so I'm going to take your words seriously.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is regards to operator precedence .

While the expression `int n = a.Max() + a.Sum() % 10;` is evaluated,

based on operator precendence , you can see that additive operations come after multiplicative.

[image]

In order to fix this, one solution is to use brackets as belows.

`int n = (a.Max() + a.Sum()) % 10;`

If you can see as per in the operator precedence, using brackets make sure to recognize the content within as an expression and evaluates it first.

You can understand on this based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2019.

As a matter of fact operator precedence of all the c based languages are similar.

Comment: it would be good to explain in your words what is written in that link. The link can die at some point in time, and then your answer will become worthless. Please consider to include the information from the link directly into your answer

Comment: This is a question about C#, not C. Pointing to how operator precedence works in C is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're facing is due to operator precedence. `%` has precedence over `+`, so what you're actually doing with your expression is:

1. Get `a.Max()`
2. Get `a.Sum() % 10`
3. Add them together

So the result is 10 + 1, which is 11.

If you *want* to take the remainder of the addition, rather than just the `a.Sum()`, you need to use parentheses: `(a.Max() + a.Sum()) % 10`. This changes the evaluation to:

1. Get `a.Max()`
2. Get `a.Sum()`
3. Add them together
4. Take the remainder after division by 10

The result of that is 1.

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be 11 because :

```
int[] a = {5, 6, 10}
int n = a.Max() + a.Sum() % 10;
n = 10 + 21 % 10 ; 
n = 10 + 1; 
n = 11;
```

if you want it to be 1 you should use proper parenthesis , only then it will prioritize the calculations:

```
int[] a = {5, 6, 10}
int n = (a.Max() + a.Sum()) % 10;
n = (10 + 21) % 10 ; 
n = 31 % 10 ; 
n = 1;
```

Comment: I believe it should be n = 10 + 21 % 10  instead of 31 ? though 21 or 31 % 10 have the same result. Some people might get confuse about the Sum() method with your equation.

Comment: And `10 + 21` not equal to `41`. It must be `n = 31 % 10`

Answer (score 0):

try this.
This is just basic mathematical grouping issue.

multiplication and division will be evaluated last after + or -

```
int[] a = {5, 6, 10};
int n = (a.Max() + a.Sum()) % 10;
Console.Write(n);
```

Comment: Why? What happens? Why would this code do what the OP expects, while his doesn't? You've posted code that outputs what the OP expects, but you did nothing to help his confusion :)

Comment: @Luaan, thanks for your comments. i updated the answer with explanation

Answer (score 0):

you should Use BOD MAS Rule here.
max value = 10, sum of all the numbers = 21, and then calculate mode.
so the solution will be :

```
10 + 21 % 10
10 + 1 = 11
```

according to the BOD MAS Rule.

Answer (score 0):

try this. This is just basic mathematical grouping issue.
(a.Max() + (a.Sum() % 10))
You can understand on this based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2019.